# Prove that $u = \sum_{k = 0}^{m - 1} c_k \delta^{(k)}$ is the solution for $x^m u = 0, \quad u \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: distribution-theory

I'm having difficulties understanding this proof.

We want to show, that $$(u, \phi) = (\sum_{k = 0}^{m - 1} c_k \delta^{(k)}, \phi)$$ under the condition that  $x^m u = 0, \quad u \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}) \text{ set of distributions on }\mathbb{R}$

For this, we define $\phi$ as follows:

$$\phi(x) = x^m \Psi (x) + \eta(x) \sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} \frac{\phi^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$$

where

$$
  \eta (x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{@{}l@{\thinspace}l}
       1  &: x \in K(0, \varepsilon)\\
       0  &: x \in K(0, 3 \varepsilon) \\
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

and

$$
  \Psi (x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{@{}l@{\thinspace}l}
       \frac{1}{x^m} (\phi(x) - \eta(x) \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{\phi^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k)  &: x \neq 0\\
       \frac{x^{(m)}}{m!} &: x = 0 \\
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

We then use the linearity of the sum and the functional to get what we want

---

I understand this, but what I don't understand is why can we define an **arbitrary** $\phi$ in such a way? This just comes like out from nowhere. I mean, if it works, then it works and it's fine, but nevertheless our $\phi$ should still be arbitrary as $(u, \phi) = (\sum_{k = 0}^{m - 1} c_k \delta^{(k)}, \phi)$ should be true for any $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ (set of test functions on $\mathbb{R}$)

FYI: $K(0, \varepsilon)$ is an open ball with the center $0$ and radius $\varepsilon$.

Comment: We don't "define" $\phi$ that way. Given some $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ we can *write* $\phi$ that way. Perhaps that was what you meant?

Comment: Yes, sorry. So my question would be: *Why*  can we write $\phi$ that way?

Comment: Do you know the fact that if $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ with $\phi^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k=0,\ldots,m-1$ then there exists $\psi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\phi(x)=x^m\psi(x)$?

Comment: No, first time I hear that. Also, that wouldn't explain the $\eta(x) \sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} \frac{\phi^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$ part

Comment: The sum is just the Maclaurin polynomial of degree $m-1$. That is then multiplied with $\eta\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ with $\eta\equiv 1$ on a neighborhood of $x=0$ to get a $C^\infty_c$ function that equals the Maclaurin polynomial on the neighborhood. Then $\phi_m(x):=\phi(x) - \eta(x) \sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} \frac{\phi^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$ satisfies $\phi^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k=0,\ldots, m-1$ so there is $\psi_m\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\phi_m(x)=x^m\psi_m(x).$

Answer (score 1):

Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}).$ Take $\eta\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\eta(x)\equiv 1$ on a neighborhood of $x=0.$

Let $T_m(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{1}{k!}x^k\phi^{(k)}(0).$ Note that $T_m \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}).$

Let $R_m = \phi - \eta\,T_m.$ We then have $R_m \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ and $R_m^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k=0,\ldots,m-1.$

We now want to show that there exists $\Psi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $R_m(x)=x^m\Psi(x).$ This follows from the theorem below.

---

**Lemma**
Let $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ with $\phi(0)=0.$ Then there exists $\psi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\phi(x) = x\psi(x).$

*Proof*
Let $\psi(x) = \int_0^1 \phi'(tx) \, dt.$ Then $\psi^{(k)}(x) = \int_0^1 t^k \phi^{(k+1)}(tx) \, dt$ is defined for all $k=0,1,2,\ldots$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ so $\psi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}).$ Also,
$$
x\psi(x) 
= x \int_0^1 \phi'(tx) \, dt
= \int_0^1 \phi'(tx) \, x \, dt
= \int_0^x \phi'(u) \, du
= \phi(x) - \phi(0)
= \phi(x),
$$
by substitution $u=xt$ and since $\phi(0)=0.$

**Theorem**
Let $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ with $\phi^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k=0,\ldots,m-1,$ where $m \geq 1.$ Then there exists $\psi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\phi(x) = x^m\psi(x).$

*Proof*
The case $m=1$ is given by the lemma.

Assume that the theorem is true for $m=p\geq 1.$ Let $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ with $\phi^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k=0,\ldots,p.$ Then, since $\phi^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k=0,\ldots,p-1,$ by the assumption there is $\psi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\phi(x)=x^p \psi(x).$ Now,
$0 = \phi^{(p)}(0) = p! \, \psi(0),$
so $\psi(0)=0$ which by the lemma implies that there is $\Psi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\psi(x)=x\Psi(x).$
Thus, $\phi(x)=x^p\psi(x)=x^p\cdot x\Psi(x)=x^{p+1}\Psi(x)$ so the theorem is true also for $m=p+1.$

By induction the theorem is true for all $m=1,2,3,\ldots$